# Linking Bash R to RStudio, Version/Package Libraries Out of Sync

Tags: r, bash, macos, homebrew, rstudio

*I am struggling with how to link/sync the version of R that I access from the bash terminal on Mac OSX to the version of R (and R libraries) that I have in R Studio.*

**Some background:**

I installed R/R studio by downloading the most recent versions available from the developer's websites as of 10/9/2016.

I previously had R installed on bash, but that version was 3.2.5 not 3.3.1 that I downloaded online. So if I tried to open an R script from bash, it would launch a deprecated version of RStudio that crashed.

To fix this, I used Brew to unlink the old version of R, and reinstall R in bash.
`brew unlink r`
`brew install R`

**The Problems:**

Now when I launch an R script from terminal, it opens the correct version of RStudio, which has a version:

`version.string R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
nickname       Bug in Your Hair`

However, if in bash I simply launch R using `$ R`, I have version:

`R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03) -- "Supposedly Educational"`

Furthermore, the packages installed in RStudio are not linked. In Rstudio I can load a package library such as `library(tidyverse)` without error.

In bash's `$ R`, the above command `library(tidyverse)` throws an error:

`Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’`

**What I would like is a way to link the bash version of R and Rstudio such that the R-versions are the same and such that packages installed in R are recognized in RStudio, and RStudio installed packages can load in bash R.**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior should be that R and Rstudio share the same versions and packages. I imagine the issue you're seeing has to do with having an outdated version of homebrew at the time of install.

I would recommend uninstalling and re-installing, as I was unable to reproduce your issue using the latest Homebrew packages:

```
brew uninstall r
brew update
brew update # (run twice)
brew cleanup
brew doctor
```

Fix any issues raised by `brew doctor`

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install r
```

I did not have Rstudio installed, so I installed it from Homebrew using cask -- This should not be necessary if you already have Rstudio installed from the developer's site.

```
brew cask install rstudio
```

After taking these steps I get the following in both R Studio and in the terminal:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) -- "Bug in Your Hair"
library(tidyverse)
Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’
```

At this point, in my *terminal window*, I ran:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
```

Finally, returning to R Studio after the install:

```
> library(tidyverse)
Loading tidyverse: ggplot2
Loading tidyverse: tibble
Loading tidyverse: tidyr
Loading tidyverse: readr
Loading tidyverse: purrr
Loading tidyverse: dplyr
Conflicts with tidy packages --------------------
filter(): dplyr, stats
lag():    dplyr, stats
```

Comment: I believe the OP is referring to the bash terminal window. Not the R command line interface.